# Flutter installation keeps failing

Tags: flutter, flutter-desktop, flutter-devtools

i want to install flutter on my mac but it keeps saying flutter not found, keeps showing this. I already set up my path and every other thing but i dont know whats wrong

Flutter (Channel unknown, 0.0.0-unknown, on macOS 13.2 22D49 darwin-x64,
locale en-US)
! Flutter version 0.0.0-unknown on channel unknown at
/Users/macbook/Development/flutter
Currently on an unknown channel. Run `flutter channel` to switch to an
official channel.
If that doesn't fix the issue, reinstall Flutter by following instructions
at https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install.
Cannot resolve current version, possibly due to local changes.
Reinstall Flutter by following instructions at
https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install.
! Warning: `flutter` on your path resolves to
/Users/macbook/development/flutter/bin/flutter, which is not inside your
current Flutter SDK checkout at /Users/macbook/Development/flutter.
Consider adding /Users/macbook/Development/flutter/bin to the front of
your path.
! Warning: `dart` on your path resolves to
/Users/macbook/development/flutter/bin/dart, which is not inside your
current Flutter SDK checkout at /Users/macbook/Development/flutter.
Consider adding /Users/macbook/Development/flutter/bin to the front of
your path.
! Unknown upstream repository.
Reinstall Flutter by following instructions at
https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install.

it was supposed to install nut it keeps giving me that error

Comment: Did you setup your path?

Comment: Yes, I put the oath of the bin folder in the zshrc file

Comment: This question needs some formatting

Comment: i want to install flutter on my mac but it keeps saying flutter not found, keeps showing this. I already set up my path and every other thing but i dont know whats wrong